# How should separated controllers access the model?

Tags: model-view-controller, application-design

Given that I've got any number of controllers, how should they access the data saved in the model?

- In a database driven application it's quite easy as all data can be fetched from one single object.
- Should there be a namespace / singleton / global object which allows access to the data?
- Should the model be passed to all controllers when they are created?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the best practice being pass around is setting up a [repository pattern](http://www.east.fi/blog/?p=230) like [so](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part5.htm) within your model to abstract the data model form data mapping. I'd go into more detail but the first link gets you there.

Comment: This is just the first approach that I've listed.